# Change MAC-Address in iOS5

Tags: cocoa, networking, ios5, jailbreak, mac-address

I Used to change my Mac Adress in Open Networks with the command:

```
ifconfig eth0 ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

in iOS4 this was no Problem, i remember there was even an App on Cydia for that. For ifconfig i instaklled network-tools from BigBoss Source.

Since iOS5 the Command is going thru Terminal without any error, however the MAC-Address isnt changing anymore... Someone a Idea on how to change it?

Answer (score 7):

It's possible. For some reason, spoofing it in iOS 5 won't work (either via command line or MacX4), but you could always rewrite it in hardware. There are several cons to this and this is not worth during unless you absolutely have to: it will **break your music player** (so you have to use VLC or the like), is **permanent** even after reboot, and effectively changes your UDID (so **betas will not work** and the **device will be unregistered**).

```
nvram wifiaddr="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
```

Again, the cons definitely outweigh the pros here. I'm sure eventually someone will come up with the software to do a spoof, not a total rewrite.

Comment: As this solution is permanent, is there a way to revert the iPhone to its original wifiaddr?

I have tried using the same method as above for recovery. However my wifiaddr is stucked with "XX:XX:XX:00:00" and it did not change to the original wifiaddr as desired.

I have did a little research and found out that using 'nvram -d wifiaddr' may help. 

My phone is now jailbroken now so I have no way to test it out. 

Would be helpful if anyone could enlighten me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. My iPad running 5.01 has an arbitrary MAC. There are no restrictions as far as playing music, and I am still able to access Apple services (at least those that I use personally) without hindrance. It's a moderately tedious process, but after a bunch of failed attempts I was able to successfully (and permanently unless I decide to repeat the process using my originals) change the values with a combination of terminal commands, DFU/recovery cycles, OSX apps, and a clean restore via iTunes. If anyone is still interested, I would be willing to outline the process. I would do so now, but I have to hash out some specifics concerning the iTunes host file.

Answer (score -1):

Because the MAC address is unchangeable for a reason?

Comment: But it doesnt mean it canot be changed... The MAC Address stays the same by the way, only the Software is delivering another Value, called MAC-Spoofing.
I need to do it because i  dont want my real MAC-Address floating around in free Networks...
Changing MAC Address worked in iOS4 with Jailbreaked iPhones and a Package from Cydia named "network-cmds" which made ifconfig availabel for iOS4, the Package work in iOS 5 but the MAC-Address dont change after the Command mentioned in the First Post, and throw no error either!